deploying simplest .net maui app on ios failing
I am getting really fed up with MAUI.
I create the template app in vs2022 17.12.0 Preview 2.1.
I deploy it to a local iphone. It runs like a champ.
I then go to nuget and update Microsoft.Maui.Controls and Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility from  8.0.72 to 8.0.91.
I deploy it to a local iphone. It runs like a champ.
I then go back to nuget and add CommunityToolkit.Maui 9.1
I deploy it to a local iphone. It fails. It compiles with no errors but when I go to run it it shows the .net splash and then crashes. It works find on android and windows.
Here's the content of the output window. Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks ... Ed
2024-10-05 10:57:48.448 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[8120:523066] Could not resolve assembly System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/56DBF6E2-EDC9-4FDD-A46E-A0D890F08DBC/Documents/Stuff.content/System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.

2024-10-05 10:57:48.445 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[8120:523066] Could not resolve assembly System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=en-GB, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/56DBF6E2-EDC9-4FDD-A46E-A0D890F08DBC/Documents/Stuff.content/System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.

[0:] An error occurred: 'Could not set up parent class, due to: Invalid generic instantiation assembly:/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/56DBF6E2-EDC9-4FDD-A46E-A0D890F08DBC/Documents/Stuff.content/Microsoft.Maui.dll type:ViewHandler`2 member:(null)'. Callstack: '   at CommunityToolkit.Maui.AppBuilderExtensions.<>c.<UseMauiCommunityToolkit>b__0_0(IMauiHandlersCollection h)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Hosting.HandlerMauiAppBuilderExtensions.HandlerRegistration.AddRegistration(IMauiHandlersCollection builder)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Hosting.Internal.MauiHandlersFactory.CreateHandlerCollection(IEnumerable`1 registrationActions)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Hosting.Internal.MauiHandlersFactory..ctor(IEnumerable`1 registrationActions)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Hosting.HandlerMauiAppBuilderExtensions.<>c.<ConfigureMauiHandlers>b__1_0(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceIdentifier, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ServiceAccessor, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].GetOrAdd(ServiceIdentifier key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiContext.WrappedServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiContext.WrappedServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[IMauiHandlersFactory](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiContext.<.ctor>b__2_0()
   at System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Maui.IMauiHandlersFactory, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Maui.IMauiHandlersFactory, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Maui.IMauiHandlersFactory, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Maui.IMauiHandlersFactory, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiContext.get_Handlers()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.SetHandler(INativeObject nativeElement, IElement element, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.SetApplicationHandler(IUIApplicationDelegate platformApplication, IApplication application, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiUIApplicationDelegate.FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
   at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(Int32 argc, String[] argv, IntPtr principalClassName, IntPtr delegateClassName) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:line 61
   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main(String[] args, Type principalClass, Type delegateClass) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:line 96
   at Stuff.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\code\dev\Stuff\Stuff\Platforms\iOS\Program.cs:line 13
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InterpretedInvoke_Method(Object obj, IntPtr* args)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span`1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)'
The app has been terminated.


What ios version do you use? Have you tried on an iphone simulator?

Does this error exist on a default maui project?

Yes, it was created using the default template. Sorry for not getting back sooner. I went down a rabbit hole on this. I disabled hot reload and it worked. I was able to run my app on ios. Trouble was,  it only worked once. The next time built ... back to square one.

As to your questions regarding what version of ios, 17.6.1.  No, I didn't spend much time on the emulator.

This is likely an issue with something in your local environment. Looking over the Maui CommunityToolkit issues I found a bug report that is similar to yours which has been resolved. You can try these steps:

Ensure latest version of XCode is installed on your dev machine
Update IDE or MAUI extensions to the latest version
Ensure the latest stable version of .NET is installed
After installing the latest stable version of .NET, open a terminal and run sudo dotnet workload install maui

source: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/2148#issuecomment-2308232294
